# Rhino Security with Oracle and Nhibernate 3.0

Tags: nhibernate, rhino-security

How to use Rhino Security from Ayende with Nhibernated Application with Oracle database?

The NHibernate version is 3.0 and I read that Rhino Security requires version 2.0.

Please provide me with the best practice

Thank you

Comment: So does Rhino.Security not compile with NHibernate 3.0?

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used Rhino Security with Oracle yet but I've recompiled it with NHibernate 3.0.
You have to download NHibernate 3.0 and all the assemblies. Remove the references to the old assemblies and substitute them with all the new ones. That's all I did and it works.